# Configuring a VM for use as a Remote Desktop Services host

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-vsphere, remote-desktop-services

I was wondering is there a good rule of thumb around configuring virtual CPUs and memory for a Windows 2008 Server R2 Remote Desktop Services host running within a VMware VM?

Our infrastructure team has suggested that two vCPUs (2x2.4 GHz AMD Opteron) and 8GB vRAM be presented to the guest for four concurrent developers running Visual Studio 2010, each with their own SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer instance on the guest, plus a couple sites per developer to use in IIS on the guest.

I was thinking that we'd want something more along the lines of having one vCPU per developer, and about three to four gigs of vRAM per developer. So, I would have expected more along the lines of 4 vCPUs and 12-16 GB vRAM.

I'd *really* appreciate a second opinion.

While researching, I *did* run across [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/64158/best-practices-for-a-remote-desktop-services-server) article here, but it was more geared toward provisioning storage.  In our case storage isn't really an issue as it is backed by our Clarion SAN which we have no control over, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend going with the smaller vCPU allocation to start. The VMWare host will have a harder time scheduling a 4 vCPU guest, so it's best to start small and add as needed. I'd stick with your infrastructure team's recommendation of 2 vCPU and 8GB RAM.